# How to change a date format in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am getting a null result when trying to change the date format,

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT("31-Mar-2022", '%d/%m/%Y');
```

What would be the right way of changing the format from 31-Mar-2022 to 2022-03-31 ?

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=55a0c655961d6450bb3350953109879f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route you want to take here in general is `STR_TO_DATE` to first convert the string date into a bona fide, followed by `DATE_FORMAT`, to convert the bona fide date back to a string in some other format.  So the following will work:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('31-Mar-2022', '%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS output;
```

But note that the default rendering of a MySQL date often will be `%Y-%m-%d`, so in this case, you probably can avoid the outer call to `DATE_FORMAT`, and just use:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('31-Mar-2022', '%d-%b-%Y') AS output;
```